# Is there a technical difference between else...if/else if?

Tags: coding-style, if-statement

I know this is going to not be the same across all languages, but it's something I've wondered for awhile.

Since the title isn't very clear, is there a technical difference between

```
if (...) {
   // ...
} else if (...) {
   // ...
}
```

and

```
if (...) {
    ...
} else {
    if (...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I know from a practical perspective, they will do the same thing, and there are readability reasons for choosing one over the other, such as if the second `if` doesn't relate directly to the first.

But from a technical perspective, I'm not sure. Do compilers tend to do something special with an `else if`, or is it handled as though it were a single line thing, like:

```
if (...)
   singleLine();
```

but looking like:

```
else
   if (...) // Counts as just a single line command
```

Hope that makes it clear what I'm asking. Is there a technical difference between the two ways of doing it, and is there any disadvantage to using the `else { if` style?

Comment: This isn't really language agnostic. A C compiler is likely smart enough to generate the same machine code for both blocks of statements. However a script language like PHP would likely generate more op codes (instructions) for the second block.

Comment: @mellowsoon Makes sense, guess I misinterpreted the right usage of the tag here

Comment: "Compiler optimization"? WTF? Seriously, people, aren't there like a billion parameters that affect performance at least ten times as much as this?!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++, the two are exactly identical. Check out the formal grammar. In the example you gave, the `if` in `else if` is really a new chunk of code, just as you've shown in your question it's analogous to a single line. The formatting and code layout is nicer with `else if`, though.

Roughly, the grammar defines:

```
<if structure> -> if <condition> <code blob> else <code blob>
<code blob> -> <if structure>
```

So when you do

```
 if (1) do(); else if (3) stuff(); else thing();`
```

the whole piece

```
 if (3) stuff(); else thing();
```

is just the `<code blob>` of the else in the first if/else structure.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure any decent compiler will generate the same code for both forms. The only reason I can think of for using the second form is that you expect to add code to the else that is not controlled by the enclosed if.